# Using recursion to put a nested structure into a dictionary without losing the structure

Tags: python, recursion, dictionary

I have an element that have items and a tag. The element can contain more elements which also have items and a tag, and those elements can also have items and a tag. Beforehand I don't know how many 'nested' elements are in the first element.

I want to save the tag and items in a dictionary with the element as key, and if the element has a 'nested' element I want to save that that element and its information in the same dictionary entry as its 'parent element'.

The code that I have so far works only if the first element has a nested element, and the nested element does not have another nested element in it. This is the code:

```
def getAllNestedElementInformation(element, nestedDict=None):
    infoDict = {'tagName':element.tag}
    infoDict.update(getItems(element))

    if nestedDict == None:
        nestedDict = infoDict
    else:
        nestedDict['nestedElement'][element] = infoDict
        print nestedDict

    for nestedElement in element:
        nestedDict.update({'nestedElement':collections.defaultdict(dict)})
        getAllNestedElementInformation(nestedElement, nestedDict=nestedDict)
```

I want to have

```
 {'name':'scan', 'nestedElement':{'name':'scanwindow', 'nestedElement':{'name:'cvParam'}}}
```

but I don't come further than

```
{'name':'scan', 'nestedElement':{'name:'scanwindow'}}
```

because I don't know how to map the next nestedElement in the the 'nestedElement' dict.

To give an example of what I have now and what I want to have, when I print nestedDict I get:

```
{'index': '0', 'nestedElement': {<Element 'scan' at 0x8068180>: {'tagName': 'scan'}}, 'tagName': 'spectrum', 'id': '1'}
{'index': '0', 'nestedElement': {<Element 'cvParam' at 0x80682a0>: {'name': 'scan start time', 'unitName': 'second', 'tagName': 'cvParam', }}, 'tagName': 'spectrum', 'id': '1'}
```

And I want to have:

```
{'index': '0', 'nestedElement': {<Element 'scan' at 0x8068180>: 'tagName': 'scan', 'nestedElement: {'name': 'scan start time', 'unitName': 'second', 'tagName': 'cvParam', }}, 'tagName': 'spectrum', 'id': '1'}
```

Comment: is `<Element 'scan' at 0xwhatever>` a valid hashable type? I feel like python wouldn't let you use that as a key.

Comment: Are you working with xml? What's the big picture problem you're trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: Yes I'm working with xml, I want to get all the nested elements in a branch of an xml tree without reading in the whole xml file.

Comment: @NiekdeKlein: If you don't read the whole file, how will you know you have *all* the nested elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to save the return value of getAllNestedElementInformation in a dictionary. Just incase someone want to know: this is what I changed my code into:

```
def getAllNestedElementInformation(element):
    infoDict = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    infoDict[element] = {'tagName':element.tag}
    infoDict[element].update(getItems(element))
    if element.text != None:
        if element.text.strip() != '':
            infoDict[element].update({'content':element.text})

    for nestedElement in element:
        infoDict[element]['nestedElement'] = getAllNestedElementInformation(nestedElement)  

    return infoDict
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks exactly the way the data is organized also in the Configuration of a tool I wrote.

You might want to look at the [InternalCfg.py](http://rmtoo.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=rmtoo/rmtoo;a=blob;f=rmtoo/lib/configuration/InternalCfg.py;h=66af1bbac7c05e62ff5d5f52f862212bcc9d3c28;hb=HEAD) file:

- `get_value()` returns a value.
- `set_value()` sets a value.

There are some other (helper) functions around - like `append_list()` adds a value to a list.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not have a recursive call. This is why you can only go down one level.

Do you maybe need to change `getAllNestedElementInformation` to `getInfo` (or vice-versa)?

Comment: That's really weird, I'm sure that my function was called getALlNestedElementInformation because I copied it right from my code... ah well, changed it back to my code

Comment: It ran from the start, I just want an extra 'layer' in the dictionary that I don't know how to add.

Comment: @NiekdeKlein That means that your code is not running correctly.